# AWK : Comparing difference of files with different delimiter

Tags: unix, awk

```
1.txt 
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|3|6

2.txt (double pipe)
1||2||3
4||5||6

expected
7|3|6
```

I want to compare 1.txt and 2.txt and print the difference . Note that the numbers of columns can vary each time

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !(a[$0])'  2.txt 1.txt
```

How can I modify the code to include delimiters in each files.

The code below works for first field alone but I am not sure how it separated the fields by double pipe

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !(a[$1])' 2.txt 1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple workaround would be to squeeze the *double delimiters* in the second file before feeding to `awk`:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !(a[$0])' <(tr -s '|' < 2.txt) 1.txt
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
7|3|6
```

---

EDIT: You assert that

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !(a[$1])' 2.txt 1.txt
```

works.  It doesn't do what you expect.  It compares only the *first* field and not the entire line.

Comment: thank you, But I thought there will be some provision within awk to handle different delimiters. But how the code (with $1)  awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !(a[$1])' 2.txt 1.txt worked .

Comment: @Awknewbie The variant that you think _works_ actually compares only the first field, not the entire line.  It is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{gsub(/\|\|/,"|",$0);a[$0]++;next} !(a[$0])' 2.txt 1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `bash` features to accomplish this:

```
diff 1.txt <(sed 's/||/|/g' < 2.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp as a delimiter in gawk, like so if you don't mind if your output is unsorted (as arrays in awk), you can do it with a single command:

```
gawk  'BEGIN {FS="\\|\\|*"} {gsub(FS,"|") ; a[$0]++} END {for (k in a) {if ( a[k] > 0 ) { print k } } }'
```

1. `BEGIN {FS="\\|\\|*"}` ==> The field separator is one or more `|`
2. `{gsub(FS,"|") ; a[$0]++}` ==> On every line normalize the number of separator `|`s to one and store the line in `a`n array, or if it's already in the `a`rray, increment the value related to it
3. `END {for (k in a) {if ( a[k] > 0 ) { print k } } }` finally print every `a`rray element where it found more than once.